# Software to record application launched from Visual Studio

Tags: windows, screen-recording, visual-studio

I'm looking for a way to record my app as I go through the motions of using it after launching it from Visual Studio.

Unfortunately my goto recording software - Dxtory - doesn't recognize the app so that's out of the question.

Does anyone know of a good solution for recording a video of software?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I might recommend [Open Broadcaster Software](https://obsproject.com/) (OBS). I've been using it for a while to record OpenGL/DirectX games, but it also has a mode for recording general desktop output.

OBS will allow you to record the output of your entire desktop or one or multiple windows. It will also allow you to optionally record your microphone. You can either save the output to a file or stream it to a live streaming service.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I tried it out but it doesn't seem to do the job for me. It will record the audio but the video records as a static picture and doesn't update.

Comment: @MasterDex Ah, that's unfortunate. Make sure you try all the modes of recording though (monitor capture, window capture, and game capture if your software is opengl/directx). More info about capture modes here: https://jp9000.github.io/OBS/general/whatcapture.html

Comment: Apologies for not accepting this as an answer sooner, I've been swamped.

Comment: It turns out that the problem with the OBS recording was due to the framerate I was recording at.